# WPF: ControlTemplate of ToggleButton will cause App to crash when binding "IsChecked" property

Tags: wpf

Edit: to reproduce this bug, you have to put the ToggleButton inside a 'non-first' `TabItem` of a `TabControl' :], like this:

```xml
<TabControl>
    <TabItem>
        <Label>Test</Label>
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem>
        <ToggleButton IsChecked="{Binding IsBusy, Mode=TwoWay}" Style="{StaticResource SwitchButton}" />
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Here is my custom `Style` of `ToggleButton`

```xml
<Style x:Key="SwitchButton" TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ToggleButton}">
                <Viewbox>
                    <Border
                        x:Name="_Border"
                        Width="40"
                        Height="20"
                        Background="#FFFFFFFF"
                        CornerRadius="10">
                        <Border.Effect>
                            <DropShadowEffect
                                Direction="0"
                                Opacity="0.3"
                                ShadowDepth="0.5" />
                        </Border.Effect>
                        <Ellipse
                            x:Name="_Ellipse"
                            Margin="2,1,2,1"
                            HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                            Fill="#FFFFFFFF"
                            Stretch="Uniform"
                            Stroke="Gray"
                            StrokeThickness="0.2">
                            <Ellipse.Effect>
                                <DropShadowEffect
                                    BlurRadius="10"
                                    Direction="260"
                                    Opacity="0.3"
                                    ShadowDepth="1" />
                            </Ellipse.Effect>
                        </Ellipse>
                    </Border>
                </Viewbox>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Checked">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="_Border"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    To="#12a5fd"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                <ThicknessAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="_Ellipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                    To="20 1 2 1"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Unchecked">
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="_Border"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                                    To="White"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                                <ThicknessAnimation
                                    Storyboard.TargetName="_Ellipse"
                                    Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                                    To="2 1 2 1"
                                    Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </EventTrigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

It works as expected when `IsChecked` is not binded:

Unchecked:

[image: unchecked]

Checked:

[image: checked]

However, when I bind the `IsChecked` property to my viewmodel, the app will crash. The error message says "System.InvalidOperationException: Name cannot be found in the namescope of System.Windows.Controls.ControlTemplate".

[image]

I found a [simalar question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27714597/9109370), and I followed what the accepted answer suggested, to use `Storyboard.Target` instead:

```
Storyboard.Target="{Binding ElementName=_Border}"
```

Using `Storyboard.Target' does eleminates the problem, the app does open normally. However, when I check the ToggleButton, it stays unchecked.

Comment: Not reproducible. Are you sure the exception is caused by the Style you are showing here?

Comment: @Clemens, I've editted the question to show how to reproduce this bug.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to replace `EventTrigger` in the `ControlTemplate` with `Trigger`:

```xml
<ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsChecked" Value="True">
        <Trigger.EnterActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="_Border"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                        To="#12a5fd"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                    <ThicknessAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="_Ellipse"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                        To="20 1 2 1"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.EnterActions>
        <Trigger.ExitActions>
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <ColorAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="_Border"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Border.Background).(SolidColorBrush.Color)"
                        To="White"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                    <ThicknessAnimation
                        Storyboard.TargetName="_Ellipse"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Margin"
                        To="2 1 2 1"
                        Duration="0:0:0.1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </Trigger.ExitActions>
    </Trigger>
</ControlTemplate.Triggers>
```

Simalar question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9135152/9109370)